# Is there a slang word for "electronic cigarettes" (e-cigarettes)?

Tags: slang

> An electronic cigarette (e-cig or e-cigarette), personal vaporizer (PV) or electronic nicotine delivery system (ENDS) is a battery-powered vaporizer which simulates tobacco smoking by producing an aerosol[1] that resembles smoke.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_cigarette

These e-cigarettes have been commercially available in some countries for a couple of years, the UK included.

Has any slang word already been coined for them? (e-smoke? e-fag?  e-dugans?)

Comment: I have a friend who calls them his _puffers_, but truth be told, I don’t know if he just invented that himself. And come to think of it, I didn’t know him back when he smoked regular cigarettes; I don’t know if he used to call those _puffers_, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The noun *vape* for some of the electronic nicotine delivery devices seems to be coming into vogue. It appears to be short for *vape pen*, which in turn is short for *vapor* or *vaporizing pen*.

A common verb form is *vaping*.

A search for *vape* shows numerous usages.

**SUPPLEMENT**: As @JLG points out, *[vape](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vape)* now appears in the *Oxford Dictionary Online*, both in verb and noun forms.

Comment: I'm British and (FWIW) I've mostly heard "e-cigs" and "e-cigarettes", sometimes "e-fags" but never "electrofags".  The nicotine "fuel" is mostly referred to as "eliquid".  Vaping is the de facto verb now but "vape" isn't used as a noun, at least not commonly.  I've seen the pipes referred to as "Vapers" but this more commonly refers to the person using it.  I think the language is still in flux.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen them referred to as *electrofags*, as seen [here](http://underdogsbiteupwards.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/electrofags-now-more-deadly-than-smoke/):-

> **Electrofags – now more deadly than smoke.**
>
> It’s been some time since I mentioned Electrofags...

This is a natural derivation from the British slang [fag](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fag#fag-3):-

> A cigarette:  ‘she’s got a fag in her mouth, and she’s squinting her
>   eyes against the smoke’ [Oxford Dictionaries]

but might not be suitable for American use, where *fag* has a different meaning.

Comment: In an American frame of thinking, _electrofag_ brings to my mind someone disparagingly discussing young gay guys who go to rave parties. I suppose one might argue they’re both full of smoke and vapour, but the connection is still somewhat far-fetched. Works fine in a British mindset, of course.

Answer (score 0):

According to the following source [fogger](http://www.e-cigarettepedia.com/2009/03/27/e-cigarette-vocabulary/) is another name for an e-cigarette:

> - fogger noun: an e-cigarette or electronic cigar

Source:http://www.e-cigarettepedia.com/2009/03/27/e-cigarette-vocabulary/

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a slang word, in my experience they are referred to as a ***dummy***.  After the thing you put in a baby's mouth to stop it crying.

This is British English usage, so I suppose in American English the equivalent would be a ***pacifier***.

Answer (score -2):

Is poof pipe wrong? I'm sure I've heard comedians come up with more entertaining and derogatory names.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please [explain your answer](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), preferably with some supporting statements and [references](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). While opinions are valued, they are not of much help as answers.